# my whatsapp showed my lastseen at 2:23 a.m ,when i had left the aap around 2:01 and was not even connected to the internet

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, whatsapp-messenger

The problem is really serious.  i need to get a solution for this.  my boyfriend thinks that I am cheating on him.

I do not know much about whats app and i have not tried doing anything. i need serious help for this. I cannot afford losing my boyfriend.
Please help.

Comment: You can turnoff Last Seen on whatsapp settings. Settings->Account->Privacy-> Set last seen to "nobody".

Comment: I cannot do that . I mean he thinks i m cheating on him and if i hide my last seen it will be more serious. I just want to know why is the last seen is showing at the time when i m not in the application

Comment: I think you have closed whatsapp on 02:01am. Is whatsapp connected using wifi or mobile data?

Comment: i was connected to wifi

Comment: wifi on android keeps scanning and gets connected if available, may be that's the problem

Comment: okay, but it shows me online even when i m not connected to the wifi??

Comment: hey, please reply anytime you come online. Please

Comment: Please don't use **all bold** – bold is for emphasis, not for panic :) I've fixed that for you now, please just remember for your next post.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: my question is "why is my whats app account showing me online when i m not using it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in whatsapp...
If you exit app properly when connected to internet then your last seen will be show actual time...

But if you are using app and disconnect internet and then exit app... then it will still show you online for some more time.. which is your case... ( I have experienced this problem many times)

So better exit app properly and then turn of the internet...

Also please check if anyone is having access of your whatsapp with web view... check in web view settings..

Comment: hey thank you  for the info.will make sure to exit the app properly now.

Comment: Welcome... Enjoy ;)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "exit app properly"?

Comment: Exit using back button... do not directly close it... or directly disconnect internet...